# How to create a Japanese slideshow in 縦書き (vertical writing direction)?

Tags: beamer, document-classes, vertical, japanese, luatexja

I'm using LuaTeX with the `luatexja` package to typeset Japanese. However, the vertical writing feature is provided in document classes (such as `ltjtarticle`), not available by just calling the package.

But I cannot do a

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{ltjtarticle} % vertical class provided by luatexja
```

or

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass[tate]{jlreq} % another class, vertical when 'tate' option is passed
```

because I don't know of a way to use two document classes.

---

A short working example of vertical writing with `luatexja` would be

```
\documentclass[landscape]{ltjtarticle}

\def\test{やまとうたは、ひとのこゝろをたねとして、よろづのことのはとぞなれりける。…そも〳〵、うたのさま、 むつなり。からのうたにも、かくぞあるべき。}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

---

The closest I can get with `beamer` as the document class is to use the `\tate` command provided by `luatexja`, but it causes a lot of problems, especially with the frame title, which remains on the top of the frame but should be on the right in vertical writing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{luatexja}

\def\test{やまとうたは、ひとのこゝろをたねとして、よろづのことのはとぞなれりける。…そも〳〵、うたのさま、 むつなり。からのうたにも、かくぞあるべき。}

\begin{document}
\tate
\begin{frame}{古今集}
\test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you add a small one page ltjtarticle document  that has a sample of vertical text small enough to fit on a beamer slide, for those of us who might be able to sort out the macros but would struggle to make a test text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just added an example of `ltjtarticle`.

Comment: As a hack, maybe wrap the whole content of each slide into an {\hbox{\tate …}}?

Comment: @AlexanderZ. I tried that. However, in this way, the title and footer would still be in the wrong place (they should be on the right and the left respectively).

Answer (score 2):

The following might be of help as a starting point, for those who know beamer macros (like margins, positioning the frame title, assembling boxes).

[image: tate example]

Possibly useful: `lltjext` package modifies `tabular`, `array` and `minipage` environments to produce vertical writing via an additional option `<t>`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\renewcommand{\kanjifamilydefault}{\gtdefault}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\usepackage{lltjext}
\def\test{やまとうたは、ひとのこゝろをたねとして、よろづのことのはとぞなれりける。…そも〳〵、うたのさま、 むつなり。からのうたにも、かくぞあるべき。\color{blue}\ruby{葛|西}{か|さい}\ }

\jfontspec[
YokoFeatures={Color=FF1900}, TateFeatures={Color=003FFF},
TateFont=HaranoAjiGothic-Regular]{HaranoAjiMincho-Regular}
\begin{document}
\tate

\begin{frame}
%\begin{minipage}<t>{1in}%
%\hspace{4em}
\frametitle{\parbox{2in}{There Is No Largest Prime Number}}
%\end{minipage}
\framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.}
%%\hfill\vbox{\hsize=40mm\raggedleft
%%\tate TATE \test}


\par\bigskip
\fbox{\vbox{\hsize=35mm
\tate
TATE \test}}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}<t>{3in}%
T2: {\small This way $\rightarrow$} \test
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```